# Liferay generates exceptions: null and javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: java, exception, sdk, liferay, portlet

I start a liferay 6.1.0 with a fresh new jsf-portlet with sdk 6.1.0 and when I try
to add the portlet to the webpage I get THIS:

```
14:12:47,672 INFO  [PortalImpl:4873] Current URL /poller/receive generates exception: null
14:13:17,625 INFO  [PortalImpl:4873] Current URL / generates exception: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.StackOverflowError
14:13:17,705 ERROR [status_jsp:670] org.apache.jasper.JasperException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.StackOverflowError
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:549)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:455)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:72)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:684)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:530)
    at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.includeLayoutContent(LayoutAction.java:412)
    at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.processLayout(LayoutAction.java:680)
    at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.execute(LayoutAction.java:244)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236)
    at com.liferay.portal.struts.PortalRequestProcessor.process(PortalRequestProcessor.java:174)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:414)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.callParentService(MainServlet.java:533)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.service(MainServlet.java:510)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:72)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:113)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:113)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:113)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:121)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.secure.SecureFilter.processFilter(SecureFilter.java:201)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:203)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:105)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:121)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.autologin.AutoLoginFilter.processFilter(AutoLoginFilter.java:240)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:203)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:105)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:684)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:471)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:402)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:329)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.FriendlyURLServlet.service(FriendlyURLServlet.java:135)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

Please tell me what goes wrong here...
Sidenote: As you can see there is a **StackOverflowError**, which indicates that this post suits PERFECTLY to this site ;)

Link to official forum: http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/20737546

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

It's a memory problem and you have to increase the size. For example, in the configuration file of server (e.g. for tomcat just double-click on server) just set :
      -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m

Another workaround is just load only 1 portlet.